# Once Upgraded my iOS Appium inspector stopped working

Tags: appium

[image: 1]

All the configurations were made for mobile ios automation and was working perfectly fine.Once I upgraded my mobile iOS to latest things stopped working, I upgraded XCode, Appium desktop, Appium inspector everything to latest. Using XCode I am able to access my mobile iOS now, but Appium inspector is failing, its showing “Gathering initial app source” and keeps looping. I am unable to downgrade iOS version to older version as its against my company policy, how to get this fixed. Tried everything from internet its not working.

Appium desktop Version - 1.22.3
Appium Inspector Version - 2022.7.1
Xcode Version - 13.4.1
iOS Version - 15.6

Comment: when you say Appium desktop version, does it mean npm package? if not, can you check what version of Appium version do you have in npm global?

Answer (score 0):

The latest update to iOS 15.6 stopped TestProject.io working a couple of weeks ago, which has now been fixed. There was a suggestion that turning on Developer Mode on the iPhone/iPad would solve the problem. It could be the same problem with the Appium Inspector(?)

Try posting here to see if anyone else has had the problem: https://github.com/appium/appium-inspector/issues